# WSO2 API Manager Publish multiple stores

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed `WSO2 API Manager, version 1.10` and I would like to know why when I publish an API to all my available tenants, can't I see this API on one of these tenant's store?

Here are my steps

1. Created some tenant at carbon using admin credentials.
2. Logged on my publisher using carbon using admin credentials.
3. Created an API and selected "available to all my tenants"
4. Logged on my stored and accessed one of my tenants.

When I logged into one of my stores I wish I could see an API, but I can't.
My API mngr is as simple as download the product, extraction and running it.

Comment: It seem to me that is not possible to have what i want..
"Although API subscription is allowed for different tenant domains, this approach has a drawback. API subscribers need to log in to own the tenant store (eng.com), then browse the hr.com store and discover the UserProfileAPI. The next section will discuss how you can make the UserProfileAPI visible in the eng.com store." extracted from http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/10/article-multitenant-api-management-with-wso2-api-manager/

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is allowed subscription to users from all the stores to api in specific tenant. If you want to publish this api to other tenants as well you need to configure the external stores as mentioned in the doc[1]

1.https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publish+to+Multiple+External+API+Stores